# X-WWW Put Request List inside of Dict

Tags: python, python-requests, x-www-form-urlencoded

Attempting to write a put request in Python that keeps getting denied - the issue seems to be that the request isn't accepting the list as value for the dict.

Any suggestions on how I can get this to be accepted?

```
import requests

key = 'Bearer abc123'
url = 'www.my_url.com'
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Accept':'application/json',
           'Authorization':key}

data = {}

data['first_name']='John'
data['last_name']='Doe'
data['employee_job[roles]'] = [{'name':'CEO'}]

r = requests.put(url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

Comment: `data['employee_job[roles]'] = [{'name':'CEO'}]` ← this line is looking like mistake. Try simple way `data = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'employee_job': {'roles':[{'name':'CEO'}]}}`

Answer (score 0):

if the server accept put request,then the problem maybe json format
you could try this,put the data as json directly,not the form encoded.
need more information to detect the problem,can you provide the api document?

```py
import requests

key = 'Bearer abc123'
url = 'www.my_url.com'
headers = {
           'Accept':'application/json',
           'Authorization':key}

data = {}

data['first_name']='John'
data['last_name']='Doe'
data['employee_job'] = {'roles':[{'name':'CEO'}]}

r = requests.put(url,json=data,headers=headers)
```